# Dynamics CRM Read/Unread Form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I'm looking to have a field populate with a special characters that marks it as read when a form is looked at in CRM. Is there a way to do this through a workflow? I'm not too proficient at JavaScript but if there's a way to mark a field as yes (in a two option set) when the form is loaded that would do the trick. Then I can use a workflow to do the rest.

Comment: Tested my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use this below snippet in form onload, this will check & set `true` in two options field for the first time.

```
if(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_yourfield") != null && Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_yourfield").getValue() == false){
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_yourfield").setValue(true);
    Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
}
```